# Android Fixed Location App

Tags: java, android, location

I have the follow code to set the current location for an app:

```
   public void setLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.getProvider(providerName) != null) {
            locationManager.removeTestProvider(providerName);
        }
        locationManager.addTestProvider(providerName, true, false, false,
                false, false, false, false, Criteria.POWER_LOW,
                Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        Location myloc = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        myloc.setLatitude(latitude);
        myloc.setLongitude(longitude);
        myloc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
        locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, myloc);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void set1001(View view) {
        final double latitude = 40.718803;
        final double longitude = -74.000193;
        setLocation(latitude, longitude);
        displayLocation();
}
```

set1001 is a `Button` click action.

The Problem is that after the location is set, it will switch back to current location. Does this set location code have to run constantly, like every second or so? Basically I would like the location to be fixed to the coordinates I specified all the time.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you want to set coordinates once and use them many times without changing

Comment: Yes that is excatly what I want to do!

Answer (score 0):

the task you wish to do can be done using `sharedpreferences`

-first get the values of coordinates as you are doing.

-now store those values in `shared preferences`.

-use the values stored in shared preferences instead of running your code to get coordinates.

-the values stored in the shared preferences will not be changed until you change them or they are removed.

you can get the example of how to set values to shared preferences from link below
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I want the other app to get the same coordinate location after my app is ran, so basically I am faking my current GPS locaiton.